# Links invisíveis enquanto não clicar em algo ou redimensionar a página

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Eu customizei um [website](http://oic.nap.usp.br), mas por algum motivo, a primeira vez que a pessoa acessa o site, o menu desaparece até que alguém clique em algo. Não consigo descobrir o por que disso.

Descobri que todo o texto da página fica invisível. Nao importa qual página seja carregada primeiro. As imagens ficam no lugar certo, o texto está lá, mas a cor parece ser igual a do fundo. (Apertar Shift+F5 [aqui](http://oic.nap.usp.br/o-que-fazemos/))

Se apertar *Inspect Element*, ou redimensionar a página, volta ao normal.

Alguma luz?

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir, de mais detalhes, em quais browsers está dando essa falha?

Comment: Em qualquer browser só no primeiro acesso. Basta apertar Shift+F5. Eu uso o Chrome. Todo o texto da página fica invisivel

Comment: Descobri o que parece ser o problema.

Desativei todos os plugins do wordpress e reativei 1 por 1. Descobri que um plugin chamado youtube está causando o problema.

Comment: Que coisa, eu acessei o link (antes de você mexer nos plugins) e não consegui ver o problema.

Comment: Aqui está a funcionar direito. Quando for assim inspeciona, e vê na consola que alguma coisa não deve estar a carregar direito. Comigo é 90% das vezes esse o caso.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é problema de incompatibilidade de plugin. Recente você atualizou o wordpress? Isso ocorre quando atualizamos o wordpress e o plugin não suporta a nova versão ainda. Aconselho a retirar esse plugin que está dando erro e procurar outro equivalente.